# How to dynamicallly pass component to a parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tabs, ngx-bootstrap

I am struggling with the passing dynamically component to a parent component here is my issue,

My template and component

```
<tabset [justified]="true">
  <tab heading="Test 1 ">
      // Default 
  </tab>
  // Dynamic tabs 
  <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [heading]="tab.title" >
     // Dynamic contents
  </tab>
</tabset>



import {
  Component, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./container.component.scss']
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  tabs: any[] = [
    {
      title: 'Test 2',
      content: AnyComponent
    },
    {
      title: 'Test 3',
      content: SomeOtherComponent
    }
  ];

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addTab(tab: any) {
    this.tabs.push(tab);
  }

}
```

What I need ... When I click the menu item from other Component(Navigator) it will use addTab() function to pass to container a dynamic component.It can be AComponent BComponent etc etc,
I tried to use NGX Bootstrap to solve this but Ngx doesnt pass the component just html or something else (or I just couldn't) 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs

Comment: It's probably a bad idea anyway. Better provide a service in the parent component, inject it into the child component and use this service to communicate between parent and child or alternatively use `@ViewChild()` to make the parent find the child.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? What's in your mind?

Comment: The child shouldn't be in business knowing about the parents API and causes unnecessary tight coupling. There are better ways anyway (as I suggested)

Answer (score 1):

First what  Günter Zöchbauer said is true, second if you know all the components there is, i mean the type (AnyComponent, OtherComponent, SomeotherComponent) then use

```
<anycomponent *ngFor=" let any of anycomponentsarray"><anycomponent>
```

same for the other

```
<Othercomponent *ngFor=" let any of othercomponentsarray"><Othercomponent>
```

if you whant to use tab array instead used like this

```
<tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [heading]="tab.title" >

<div *ngIf="tab.content === anycomponent">
<anycomponent><anycomponent>
<div>

<div *ngIf="tab.content === othercomponent">
<othercomponent><othercomponent>
<div>
  </tab>
```

anyway component shouldnt be use as variable like this if you can avoid it.
Use a service for communication between components

[this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) for more information

Comment: thank you for your interest it seems true i'll check